# Does this sentence in bold sound natural?

Tags: grammar

Does the sentence in bold sound natural although I use "can't" instead of "won't be able to"?

A: You are not going anywhere but home after school. I need you to clean your room and help me fix the car.

B: Damn, that sucks. Mike and Amy are going to a party. **If I don’t go with them, I can’t meet some cool people tonight**