# Is it possible to use “can’t” in a conditional 1 sentence instead of “won’t be able to”?

Tags: grammar

Is it possible to use “can’t” to refer to future inability instead of “won’t be able to” in the main clause of a type 1 conditional sentence?

Like this:

If it rains heavily, he can’t hold his party in the park next weekend.

I am not sure if it’s okay. Can you guys give me more examples?

Comment: Yes, the wording works just fine.

Comment: This might help. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/69865/how-can-i-say-can-in-the-future-form

Comment: @YosefBaskin Is there any more example like the one I came up with?

Comment: The negation is syntactically irrelevant. It's the same situation with *If it's sunny, **he can / he'll be able to** hold his party in the park next weekend.*

Comment: How long before you finally believe that "can" and its negative counterpart "can't" is also used to denote future events? **1.** [If he uses a rifle…](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/347092/) **2.** [Does using "can" instead of "will be able to" make this sentence in bold sound unnatural?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/346908/) **3.** [If they receive heavy weapons…](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/347081/) **4.** [If you work hard enough next month](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/346946/)

Comment: Instead of repeatedly posting the same type of question–and risking a question ban–why don't you explain why the answers to your previous questions did not satisfy you?

Comment: and **5.** [Does this sentence in bold sound natural?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/345825/) which is almost a duplicate of  this one: `If I don’t go with them, I can’t meet some cool people tonight`